# Non-Public Members access in windows store

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-store-apps

I want to access Non-Public Member in windows store apps but i cant.

[image]

I want to access the "elements" in picture

I have a `GridView` that binds to a collection for grouping as follows

```
private void gridview_1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    slidein_history_of_illness.DataContext = (sender as GridView).SelectedItem;
    object obj = (sender as GridView).SelectedItem;
}
```

The `ItemSource` of my `GridView`  is `GridViewItemSoure`:

```
List<GroupInfoList<object>> GridViewItemSoure = new List<GroupInfoList<object>>();

var query = from item in Collection
            orderby ((Item)item).name
            group item by ((Item)item).name into g
            select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };

foreach (var g in query)
{
    GroupInfoList<object> info = new GroupInfoList<object>();
    info.Key = g.GroupName;

    foreach (var item in g.Items.GroupBy(x=>((Item)x).color))
        info.Add(item);

    GridViewItemSoure.Add(info);
}
```

Comment: Don't bind to something whos type is object, bind to something with an actual type.  You don't have access to all the reflection methods in the windows store and besides they are slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that!

I access elements with this lines!

```
private void gr_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    object obj = (sender as GridView).SelectedItem;
    IGrouping<string, object> groupCast = obj as System.Linq.IGrouping<string, object>;
    foreach (Item item in groupCast)
       {
          //to do staff
       }
  }
```